# Expand and fill an array by repeating initial values in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

If I have an array1: 1, 21, 30

The current size is 3

If I want to expand the array to size n, and populate the extra indices by repeating the values from the initial array, how can I do it in C#?

For example, say n = 8, the out put should be an array with values 1, 21, 30, 1, 21, 30, 1, 21

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally untested, but this should get you started:

```
int initialSize = myArr.Length
Array.Resize(ref myArr, 8);
for(int i = initialSize;i< myArr.Length; i++)
{
   myArr[i] = myArr[ i % initialSize ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use modulo you can find the right element in your initial array as you build your final array.

```
const int[] patternArray = { 1, 21 , 30 };

int[] array = new int[n];  
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    int patternIdx = i % 3;
    array[I] = patternArray[patternIdx];
}
```

Note: I wrote this on my cell so apologies for any minor syntax issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use a generic `List<T>` to store your array to allow for it to grow as needed. You can use its [AddRange()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) method to add multiple values.

Comment: If he's only resizing once, does it still make sense to use List?

Comment: It may. It really depends on the OP's requirements.